# App-engine-go component not available in component list on ARM/raspberry pi

Tags: linux, google-app-engine, raspberry-pi, arm, raspberry-pi3

After [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906157) was fixed, the appengine team recommends usage of the x86 Linux source for installation on ARM environments like the raspberry pi 3.

After downloading the gcloud sdk, when I run `gcloud components list` on raspberry pi, I get the following component list

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                        Components                                        |
+---------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
|     Status    |                Name               |            ID            |    Size   |
+---------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
| Not Installed | Cloud Datalab Command Line Tool   | datalab                  |   < 1 MiB |
| Not Installed | Cloud Datastore Emulator          | cloud-datastore-emulator |  17.7 MiB |
| Not Installed | Cloud Datastore Emulator (Legacy) | gcd-emulator             |  38.1 MiB |
| Not Installed | Cloud Pub/Sub Emulator            | pubsub-emulator          |  33.2 MiB |
| Not Installed | gcloud Alpha Commands             | alpha                    |   < 1 MiB |
| Not Installed | gcloud Beta Commands              | beta                     |   < 1 MiB |
| Not Installed | gcloud app Java Extensions        | app-engine-java          | 116.0 MiB |
| Not Installed | gcloud app PHP Extensions         | app-engine-php           |           |
| Not Installed | gcloud app Python Extensions      | app-engine-python        |   6.2 MiB |
| Installed     | BigQuery Command Line Tool        | bq                       |   < 1 MiB |
| Installed     | Cloud SDK Core Libraries          | core                     |   7.4 MiB |
| Installed     | Cloud Storage Command Line Tool   | gsutil                   |   3.3 MiB |
+---------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
```

When I run the same on a x86_64 system, I get the following list.

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                  Components                                                 │
├───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┬───────────┤
│     Status    │                         Name                         │            ID            │    Size   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ Not Installed │ App Engine Go Extensions                             │ app-engine-go            │  97.7 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Cloud Bigtable Command Line Tool                     │ cbt                      │   4.0 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Cloud Bigtable Emulator                              │ bigtable                 │   3.5 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Cloud Datalab Command Line Tool                      │ datalab                  │   < 1 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Cloud Datastore Emulator                             │ cloud-datastore-emulator │  17.7 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Cloud Datastore Emulator (Legacy)                    │ gcd-emulator             │  38.1 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Cloud Pub/Sub Emulator                               │ pubsub-emulator          │  33.2 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Emulator Reverse Proxy                               │ emulator-reverse-proxy   │  14.5 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Google Container Local Builder                       │ container-builder-local  │   3.7 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Google Container Registry's Docker credential helper │ docker-credential-gcr    │   2.2 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ gcloud Alpha Commands                                │ alpha                    │   < 1 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ gcloud Beta Commands                                 │ beta                     │   < 1 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ gcloud app Java Extensions                           │ app-engine-java          │ 116.0 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ gcloud app PHP Extensions                            │ app-engine-php           │  21.9 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ gcloud app Python Extensions                         │ app-engine-python        │   6.2 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ kubectl                                              │ kubectl                  │  12.2 MiB │
│ Installed     │ BigQuery Command Line Tool                           │ bq                       │   < 1 MiB │
│ Installed     │ Cloud SDK Core Libraries                             │ core                     │   7.4 MiB │
│ Installed     │ Cloud Storage Command Line Tool                      │ gsutil                   │   3.3 MiB │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

Are the missing components because of the platform incompatibility or is there a way around to get the golang sdk working on a raspberry pi?

Answer (score 1):

As I interpret the comments in the issue tracker:

1. I don't see any mention of a "source" installation
2. they say only that the "pure python" parts should work (the SDK is mostly Python scripts, AIUI)

So I believe the answer is no, the Go App Engine SDK does not work on ARM, and there do not seem to be any plans to support it.

Comment: As of 31-12-21: app-engine-go still not available on the arm64v8 version of google-cloud SDK